# Responsive drop down menu not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive drop down navigation menu for my webpage. I already have a working drop down menu, but I want to make it so that when the screen reaches a certain size, I get a ☰ icon with my menu items. However, when I test this (by re-sizing my browser), I only see my drop down menu displayed as a block element, and the ☰ icon doesn't show. Here is a fiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwdc4/

My JavaScript code is in an external file. This is what the file looks like:

```
$("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776; </div>');
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggle();

});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768){
        $("#nav").removeAttr("style");

    }
});
```

And my import to HTML:

```
<head>
 <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav-menu.css"
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="nav-menu.js"></script> 
  </head>
```

What is wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle actually works. Just add a jQuery version in the left panel

Comment: @NathanP. I am using chrome and even with jQuery I am seeing the same behavior as the poster. No ☰ icon.

Comment: @MathewMacLean [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwdc4/3/) works for me

Comment: @NathanP. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well and it still won't render. It works on the fiddle, but not in my browser.

Comment: Maybe it's an encoding issue, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwdc4/4/). I'm on chromium, on Arch 64bits

Comment: @NathanP. I've tried in IE, Firefox, and Chrome and your newest fiddle still wont display.

Comment: @MathewMacLean you don't even see `HERE` ?

Comment: @NathanP. That was my fault. I'm out of it. I wasn't thinking that due to it being responsive, the ☰ icon only appears when your shrink the results screen. Your comments do indeed work.

Comment: @Rebecca have you tried re sizing the results pane?

Comment: @Mathew, I tried but I still cannot see the icon. However, I see it on the fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jquery library to use the $ object

Add this line in your HTML to use it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Or choose your version directly on the jQuery website http://jquery.com/download/

Updated fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwdc4/1/